# How to generate a std::get like function for my class?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

For example, I have a class

```
struct A {int a; bool b;};
```

And I want to generate a template function to get its elements (like the std::get to get a tuple element)

```
template<unsigned i, class T>
auto Get(T& t);

template<>
int& Get<0, A>(A& a)
{
    return a.a;
}

template<>
bool& Get<1, A>(A& a)
{
    return a.b;
}


int main()
{
    A a;
    Get<0>(a) = 10;
    Get<1>(a) = true;
    return 0;
}
```

The above code doesn't work. The challenge is that I don't know the returned type of Get for arbitrary class. Any way to implement it? Thanks.

Comment: Define "doesn't work" please

Comment: You may not partially specialize function templates. You'll have to provide some mechanism inside `struct A` if you want `Get` to work on different types (or a traits-like approach). For tuple-like classes, you could use tricks with variadic templates.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Assuming you wouldn't mind making this in a "manual manner" you can do this really simply.

```
#include <tuple>

struct A {
    int a; bool b;
};

template<size_t N>
auto get(A& a) -> decltype(std::get<N>(std::tie(a.a, a.b))) {
    return std::get<N>(std::tie(a.a, a.b));
}

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    A a;
    get<0>(a) = 10;
    get<1>(a) = true;
    std::cout << a.a << '\n' << a.b;
}
```

Output:

```
10
1
```

Comment: use `std::tie` instead of `std::forward_as_tuple` and you got my vote.